# Change Background of SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-settings

i am tring to create a settings screen using **androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen**.

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="enable"
    app:title="@string/sync_title"/>

<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="missed"
    app:summary="Remove missed calls and block unwanted ones"
    app:dependency="enable"
    app:title="Missed call alert" />

<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="blocked"
    app:dependency="enable"
    app:summary="Receive a silent notification when you receive an unwanted call"
    app:title="Be informed of blocked calls " />


<PreferenceCategory
    app:key="premium_cat"
    app:dependency="enable"
    app:title="Premium">


    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="premium"
        app:dependency="enable"
        app:summary="Automatically identify spam calls"
        app:title="Real time call alert" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

the problem i have is the i want to add a different background color for the first settings

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
app:key="enable"
app:title="@string/sync_title"/>
```

i tried adding a layout but it does not work all it does is hide the **SwitchPreferenceCompat**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

Create a new java class extended from `SwitchPreferenceCompat`

```
public class MySwitchPreference extends SwitchPreference {

    public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MySwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MySwitchPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.your_color); // put here the color defined in colors.xml
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this

```
<com.your_package.your_name.MySwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="enable"
    app:title="@string/sync_title"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems like onBindView isn't used by SwitchPreferenceCompat anymore.
Now I implemented it like this in Kotlin:

```
internal class MySwitchPreference : SwitchPreferenceCompat {

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
    holder?.itemView?.let { view ->
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.your_color)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i dont need need to add

`<com.your_package.your_name.MySwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="enable"
    app:color="@color/color"
    app:title="@string/sync_title"/>`

Comment: it works but i had issues because i am using androidx

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @AyodeleKayode I also use Androidx and it works well. What issues have you found?